# How to bind new value to a variable in Racket while continuing loop

Tags: loops, functional-programming, scheme, racket, variable-assignment

I have a 2D list of numbers in a way that represents the entries of a table, e.g.:

```
'((0 2 3)
  (4 0 0)
  (7 0 9))
```

and the goal is to mark the zeros in a way that each row and each column has *only one* *marked* 0. So in this example, the marked zeros would be `(col 1 row 1) (col 2 row 3) (col 3 row 2)`. It is a step of the [Hungarian Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

I'm trying to write this block of pseudocode in Scheme, and I'm having problem modifying my variables without restarting the loop. I don't know how to change a variable and continue form that line.

```
for r in rows
  first := true
  for c in cols
     if A(r, c) == 0
        if first
           A(r, c) is assigned
           first := false
           for rr in rows
              if A(rr, c) == 0 and r != rr
                 A(rr, c) is crossed out
        else
           A(r, c) is crossed out
```

For example, assigning `false` to `first`, or crossing / assigning `A(r, c)`. How to do that?

I have tried to use named `let` for each loop but I can't find another way to bind a new value to a variable without restarting the `let` loop.

Comment: Use `set!` to assign a value to a variable like `first`. For assignment to `A(r, c)`, it depends on what your `A` is. If it's a (mutable) vector, then you need `vector-set!`. If it's a (mutable) hash, then you need `hash-set!`. That being said, if you really want to follow the "functional programming" style, you should try to restructure your program to avoid these assignments.

Comment: There is almost certainly a better solution that doesn't involve looping and assignments. In particular, if your aim is to program functionally, you can't use this code and need to start over. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: what is the meaning of "is assigned"? what is the meaning of "is crossed out"?

Comment: I have a 2D list of numbers in a way that represents the entries of a table ex: '((0 2 3)(4 0 0)(7 0 9)) and the goal is to mark the zeros in a way that each row/column has only one marked 0. So in the example that I gave, the marked zeros would be (col 1 row 1) (col 2 row 3) (col 3 row 2). It is a step of the Hungarian Algorithm.

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63078536/849891) for a possible direction.

Comment: what is the meaning of "is assigned", in Scheme terms? what is the meaning of "is crossed out", in Scheme terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am slightly confused by what you are trying to do but I think it is this: given some matrix A, return the largest possible set of 'assignments' (r, c), where, for each assignment (r, c) A(r, c) = 0, and each r or c occurs no more than once in the set.  I'll define a 'complete' set of assignments to be a set of assignments which includes an assignment for each row (obviously no such set exists for any matrix with more rows than columns).

If that is correct, then here is an approach to doing it in Racket which does not use any assignment.

Firstly here is a little module which lets you construct numerical matrices: there is unquestionably a much more industrial-strength version of numerical matrices included with Racket, but I already have this and I'm lazy.  Matrices are represented as functions which

- when called with no arguments return the dimensions of th matrix;
- when called with two arguments return the element at that index;
- (when called with a single argument do the equivalent of Common Lisp's `row-major-aref`, which was used for debugging).

Note that matrices are immutable.

```lisp
(module matrix racket
  ;; mindless numerical matrices
  (provide (contract-out
            (make-matrix
             (-> (listof (listof number?))
                 (case->
                  (-> (values natural-number/c natural-number/c))
                  (-> natural-number/c number?)
                  (-> natural-number/c natural-number/c number?))))))

  (define (make-matrix rows)
    (let* ([r (length rows)]
           [c (if (> r 0)
                  (for/fold ([cl (length (first rows))])
                            ([col (in-list (rest rows))])
                    (if (and cl (= cl (length col))) cl #f))
                  0)]
           [s (* r c)])
      (unless c
        (error 'make-matrix "not rectangular"))
      (let ([v (for*/vector ([row (in-list rows)]
                             [e (in-list row)])
                 e)])
        (case-lambda
          ;; A matrix is a function which ...
          [()
           ;; ... with no arguments returns its dimensions ...
           (values r c)]
          [(index)
           ;; ... with one argument does row-major-aref ...
           (when (>= index s)
             (error 'matrix "index out of range"))
           (vector-ref v index)]
          [(row col)
           ;; ... with two arguments does aref.
           (when (or (>= row r) (>= col c))
             (error 'matrix "indices out of range"))
           (vector-ref v (+ (* row c) col))])))))
```

So, OK, given that we can write a function which will compute the assignments.  Almost all the hard part of this (which you may not need) is, if there is no complete set of assignments (for instance if the matrix has a row with no zeros) returning the biggest set it can find.  On the other hand for a matrix with many possible sets of assignments, the function below just returns one.

First of all I wanted some way of representing tables of assignments: I need to be able to ask if an assignment is in the table already and how big the table is, and extend it with a new assignment, returning a new set of assignments.  It's good if most of these operations take something approximating constant time, but they don't have to.  I also want to be able to turn a table of assignments into a list of `(row column)` lists, sorted by row.

So here is that, implemented in terms of Racket's dictionary interface:

```lisp
(define empty-assignments '())

(define assignments-count dict-count)

(define assignments-has-col? dict-has-key?)

(define (extend-assignments a col row)
  ;; Return a new set of assignments which extends a by col and row
  (when (assignments-has-col? a col)
    (error 'extend-assignments "adding an existing assignment"))
  (if (null? a)
      (hasheqv col row)
        (dict-set a col row)))

(define (assignments->list assignments)
  (sort (dict-map assignments (λ (col row) (list row col)))
        < #:key car))
```

And finally, given all that, here is a function which computes assignments.  There really is one big trick to this which is that when the loop over columns (the inner loop) finds an assignment, it calls the row loop with the new assignments and adds a restart, which is simply a function that can be called to restart the search from this column and row.

This function will either compute a complete set of assignments or fail: it won't return a 'best' set if there is no complete set.

```lisp
(define (assignify m)
  ;; compute a set of assignments for m, or return #f
  (let-values ([(rows cols) (m)])
    (let row-loop ([row 0]
                   [assignments empty-assignments]
                   [restarts '()])
      (if (= row rows)
          ;; we've got to the end
          (cond [(= (assignments-count assignments) rows)
                 ;; found enough assignments, we're done
                 (assignments->list assignments)]
                [(not (null? restarts))
                 ;; not enough assignments, but there are things to try
                 ((first restarts))]
                 [else
                  ;; fail
                  #f])
          ;; this is not the end
          (let col-loop ([col 0])
            (cond [(= col cols)
                   ;; out of columns, loop on the next row
                   (row-loop (+ row 1) assignments restarts)]
                  [(and (zero? (m row col))
                       (not (assignments-has-col? assignments col)))
                   ;; found an assignment, loop on the next row with
                   ;; the assignment, pushing a restart
                   (row-loop (+ row 1)
                             (extend-assignments assignments col row)
                             (cons (thunk (col-loop (+ col 1))) restarts))]
                  [else
                   ;; loop on next column
                   (col-loop (+ col 1))]))))))
```

If in addition you want the function to return one of the the biggest possible sets of assignments if there is no complete set then the function gets a fair bit more complicated and harder to understand:

```lisp
(define (assignify m)
  ;; Compute one of the best assignments for a matrix m
  ;;
  (let-values ([(rows cols) (m)])
    (let row-loop ([row 0]
                   [assignments empty-assignments]
                   [best-assignments empty-assignments]
                   [restarts '()])
      (if (= row rows)
          ;; we've got to the end
          (cond [(= (assignments-count assignments) rows)
                 ;; found enough assignments, we're done
                 (assignments->list assignments)]
                [(not (null? restarts))
                 ;; not enough assignments, but there are things to try
                 ((first restarts)
                  (if (> (assignments-count assignments)
                         (assignments-count best-assignments))
                      assignments
                      best-assignments))]
                [else
                 ;; Return the best we have
                 (assignments->list
                  (if (> (assignments-count assignments)
                         (assignments-count best-assignments))
                      assignments
                      best-assignments))])
          ;; this is not the end
          (let col-loop ([col 0]
                         [best best-assignments])
            (cond [(= col cols)
                   ;; out of columns, loop on the next row
                   (row-loop (+ row 1)
                             assignments best
                             restarts)]
                  [(and (zero? (m row col))
                       (not (assignments-has-col? assignments col)))
                   ;; found an assignment, loop on the next row with
                   ;; the assignment, pushing a restart
                   (let ([ia (extend-assignments assignments col row)]
                         [rss (cons (λ (ba)
                                      (col-loop (+ col 1) ba))
                                    restarts)])
                     (row-loop (+ row 1) ia
                               (if (> (assignments-count ia)
                                      (assignments-count best))
                                   ia
                                   best)
                               rss))]
                  [else
                   ;; loop on next column
                   (col-loop (+ col 1) best)]))))))
```

And now

```lisp
> (define m1 (make-matrix '((0 2 3)
                            (4 0 0)
                            (7 0 7))))
> (define m2 (make-matrix '((0 2 3)
                            (4 0 0)
                            (7 7 7))))
> (assignify m1)
'((0 0) (1 2) (2 1))
> (assignify m2)
'((0 0) (1 1))
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was aiming for. A way to solve it by avoiding assignment

Comment: if it is exactly what you wanted, you should consider accepting it (clicking the big check-mark next to it) @Pauf3998